# Angular 4 Reactive Forms protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli, angular2-forms

I'm trying to test with protractor the validation code of an input form in my App.

My component looks more or less like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  private myForm: FormGroup;
  private category: AbstractControl;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      'category': ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.category = this.myForm.controls['category'];
  }
...
}
```

In this simplified version category is the *only* input field of my form.

In turn *my-component.component.html*:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" class="new-item-form">
      <input type="text" name="category" title="Hochladen"
             placeholder="Enter a category"
             [formControl]="category">
      category.isValid = <pre>{{category.valid | json}}</pre>
      <br>
      category.value<pre class="test">{{category.value | json}}</pre>
      <br>
      <div *ngIf="!category.valid && (!category.pristine)"
           class="ui error message">Document category not valid</div>
</form>
```

... In other words the Text showing *Document category not valid* is only shown if the form field has been played with but still left blank. So far so good, it's also working perfectly until here. The **pre** tags are just a help so have a visual reminder of what is going on.

The real issue comes when I try to test this behavior using protractor. In which case, given *app.e2e-spec.ts*:

```javascript
describe('Form validation', () => {
  it('should show missing category validation error if category is missing after field edited', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    let categoryInput = element(by.css('form.new-upload-form input[name="category"]'));
    categoryInput.sendKeys('abc');
    expect(categoryInput.getAttribute('value')).toBe('abc');
    categoryInput.clear();

    expect(categoryInput.getAttribute('value')).toBe('');

    let errorMessages = element.all(by.css('.ui.error.message'))
    expect(errorMessages.count()).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

All expect calls succeed with the exception of the last one ie. `expect(errorMessages.count()).toBe(1);`. That meaning that the error message is never displayed.

This only happens as long as operated by protractor. And as long as that is true, `category.isValid` is always true. And after the initial `categoryInput.sendKeys('abc');`, `category.value` stays **always** at `'abc'`.

I've tried doing a bunch of `categoryInput.click();` or `bodyElement.click()` to no avail. I've also tried using several `categoryInput.sendKeys('\ue003');`(backspace) instead/in-addition of `categoryInput.clear()`. Also just inputting a `'\ue003'`(instead of `'abc'`) won't have any efect(and it shouldn't either) on `category.pristine`.

On a quest for knowledge I'll proceed reading into the source code of `ReactiveFormsModule` in an attempt to understand how `categoryInput.sendKeys(...)` or `categoryInput.clear` are ignored.

Before I forget, I'm using protractor = 5.1.0, @angular/cli = 1.0.0, @angular/common = 4.0.0 ... @angular/forms = 4.0.0

Thanks for making it until here, and even more so if you think you can help.

Comment: Did you try to call `categoryInput.sendKeys("")`after `categoryInput.clear();`?
I think another idea could be to submit the form, would that be a possibility?

Comment: Are there any events on the component that you can trigger? for example do a `blur` on the component after making it empty. As far as I understand from your description that is not what is happening now.

Comment: Thanks @Batajus, `categoryInput.sendKeys("")` after the `categoryInput.clear()` doesn't help. I'm now trying to bypass the whole 'pristine' code so that it correctly works.

Comment: Thanks @wswebcreation, I've tried `blur` by clicking outside the input field(disabled submit button) but it doesn't seem to help. I have tried triggering an 'input' event on the `categoryInput` field, but I couldn't figure out how to do that with protractor.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4343) on the GitHub page for Angular.

However, there is a workaround that can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/301#issuecomment-32651201).

Which is selecting all in the input and hit backspace, and then submit the form will trigger validation errors to be displayed.

For example, this worked for me (I am running Angular 6, Protractor 5.4.1)

```js
field.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a"));
field.sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
button.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you. With this code you are injecting a piece of javascript to reset the input and trigger a blur.

```js
function tiggerJsBlur(element) {
  var blurField = new Event('blur');
  element.value = '';
  element.dispatchEvent(blurField);
}

browser.executeScript(tiggerJsBlur, categoryInput.getWebElement());
```

Comment: `triggerJsBlur` didn't trigger the blur on the `categoryInput` element. This did it though. calling `element.blur()` in `triggerJsBlur` instead of `element.dispatchEvent()` successfully blurs the field, but it doesn't succeed in displaying the error message.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution ?